# npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! syscall mkdir

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm

I ran this in vscode

```
npm install eslint-plugin-react-hooks --save-dev
```

After running

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path D:\Users\AOM\node_modules\.corepack-zcmWVMs
```

Please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acfpv.png)

Comment: your image didn't load correctly, you need to fix it. Also, any commands you enter should be wrapped in 3x back-tics, (e.g. `\`\`\` CODE HERE \`\`\``) so they  are displayed as code.

Comment: I fixed it. can you see the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, since there is not much description here, but the problem can be solved by creating a directory in drive other than "C" so try that or just don't try to run above command in existing folders provided by Windows like `Desktop/Download/Documents/Pictures/Users` etc
If this does not work please explain what you are trying to do here

Comment: I want to install ESLint Plugin in my react project. I ran npm install eslint-plugin-react-hooks --save-dev in terminal but error. I don't know what to do because my code can't run

Comment: I understand, but like I said, windows can cause problems when you are doing risky task with npm in folders(like `Desktop/Download/Documents/Pictures/Users`)  where sensitive information can be available, so please move you project to another directory and try again.

Comment: otherwise you can try deleting `node_modules` and do `npm install` again, followed by eslint command that you are trying to do